# Trouble adding an onkeypress event to a textbox outside of the input tag

Tags: javascript, events, runtime, addition

I need to add an event to a text box without modifying the input tag itself.  I created a function which will check to make sure only letters are entered and not allow numbers or symbols.  I have to code for this and it is functional... when inserted inside of the input tag, I am having trouble in adding this event elsewhere in my code.  Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the inputs that you are interested in monitoring. Then subscribe each of them to a function and your event.

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) talks about traditional event mapping here and also has links to W3C standard events.

So gather all your inputs and then attach your event to them

```
Pseudocode:
var elementArray = getAllInputElements();
for (var element in elementArray) {
    element.onclick = myfunction;
}
```